# What is d in a boolean function?

Tags: karnaugh-map

I know if it's \$ \Sigma \$ we put 1's in the Karnaugh map, but I don't know what \$ d \$ is.

$$ f(a,b,c,d) = \Sigma m(0,1,4,10,15) + d(7,14) $$

From what I've googled, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map it seems to be a "don't care", but I'm not so sure, because this is the first time I've seen this, and on the link and no where else can I see a \$ d() \$ reference.

Comment: You are correct.  It is Don't Care!  Kind of strange since d is also an input.

Comment: I should use X in place of d. m is abbreviation for "minterm" ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of d(...) being used for don't care conditions marked with an X: -

[image]

Image from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-significance-of-the-dont-care-condition-in-a-Karnaugh-map). Here's another example: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse467/99au/admin/Slides/Week1Lecture2/sld025.htm).